# jscroll pane, jquery tools :: tabs problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-tools

jScrollPane has a very reasonable problem when working with tabs. Tabs (both jQuery UI and jQuery Tools) usually use `display: none` to hide unfocused tabs. This messes jScrollPane up. The fix is instead of `display: none;` to write something like `position: absolute; left: -10000px;`.

Unfortunately in jQuery Tools I don't see any idea how to do this myself. There's no CSS class  jQuery Tools use for hidden tabs that I can override.

Any ideas on how to hack this together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can override the default effect. Check out the bottom of this page in the [docs of jQuery Tools.](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html#events) Instead of the default `hide()` which sets `display:none;` you could set the css yourself.

```
$.tools.tabs.addEffect("default", function(tabIndex, done) {

    // hide all panes and show the one that is clicked
    //this.getPanes().hide().eq(tabIndex).show();

        this.getPanes().css({position: 'absolute', left: '-10000px'}).eq(tabIndex).css({{position: 'relative', left: '0'}});

        // the supplied callback must be called after the effect has finished its job
    done.call();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! thank you so much! give me your home address and i'll send you the gift of a thousand suns!